# 'Series' object has no attribute 'iplot'

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter

I have been trying to figure this problem out for the last 2 hours and keep coming up short on how to solve this error - have viewed youtube videos, went through stackoverflow, and I cannot understand where this is going wrong. 
Please note I am working on an assignment, using Anaconda and Jupyter notebooks, with Python 3.

```
#Import Libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Plotly Tools
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as offline
offline.init_notebook_mode()
from plotly import tools
import plotly.tools as tls
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

#Import CSV as a Pandas Dataframe
fp = pd.read_csv("gun-violence-data_01-2013_03-2018.csv")

#Confirm that dataset was properly loaded
fp.head()
```

After importing the libraries, I cleaned up the data a bit and put it into the dataframe 'fp_clean'. When I try to plot:

```
temp = fp_clean["state"].value_counts().head(30)
temp.iplot(kind='bar')
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-261d72eb2ae5> in <module>
      4 #temp.plot(kind='bar')
      5 temp = fp_clean["state"].value_counts().head(30)
----> 6 temp.iplot(kind='bar')
      7 #temp.iplot(kind='bar', xTitle = 'State name', yTitle = "# of incidents", title = 'Top States with highest number of Gun Violence', filename='Bar')
      8 #temp.plot(kind='bar')

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   4374             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   4375                 return self[name]
-> 4376             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   4377 
   4378     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iplot'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Exactly what it says: `temp = fp_clean["state"]....` is a Series, not a DataFrame, and doesn't have an `iplot` method. Look at the output of `dir(temp)` and tell us if it has any plot methods. I think you want to select a single column (Series), but keep the result as a DataFrame, so do `fp_clean.loc[:, ['state']])`

Comment: You imported an `iplot` function.  That's a function, not a `method` of the pandas `Series` object.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `temp` object here is a [`pandas.series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) object which does not have a `iplot` method when not linked to plotly. We need [`cufflinks`](https://plot.ly/python/v3/ipython-notebooks/cufflinks/) to link plotly to pandas and add the `iplot` method:

```py
import cufflinks as cf
cf.go_offline()
cf.set_config_file(offline=False, world_readable=True)
```

After this, try plotting directly from the dataframe:

```py
fp_clean["state"].iplot(kind="bar")
```

( If you don't have cufflinks get it with : `pip install cufflinks --upgrade`)